# '[WXWIN root]/lib/vc_lib/mswd/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have installed WxWidgets 3.1.1, added the `WXWIN` environment variables, and used `Build All` with the `wx_vc15.sln` file.  While trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <wx/wx.h>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

}
```

I am hit with this error:

`Error  C1083   Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc_lib/mswd/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory`

I go into `[WXWIN root]\lib\vc_lib`, there are only `mswu` and `mswud` there.  How come the error complains about something inside `mswd` which doesnt exist?  Could someone please help me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` in your project settings (which is normally the default for the new projects).

This is mentioned in the [instructions for setting up your project](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.1/docs/msw/install.txt#L491).

Comment: how do I do that from the .sln file?  Is it in this block here in platform.h? #if wxUSE_UNICODE
#   ifndef _UNICODE
#       define _UNICODE
#   endif
#   ifndef UNICODE
#       define UNICODE
#   endif
#endif

Comment: But then, the link says "It should not be necessary to do this."

Comment: You do it in your _project_ settings, inside the IDE. This is however the default since a very long time, so I have no idea why isn't it already the case for you if you didn't change it yourself.